# How do I post a JSON request in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I am sending the following JSON request;

```
 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass));
JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login, "POST", params);
```

It generates the following string `email=xxx, password=xxxx`, but I want the string generated to be in JSON format (i.e `"email":"xxx","password":"xxxx"`). How can I get it to do this?

Comment: Take a look into Volley. It makes life lot easier. Here is a small tutorial -  http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `JSONObject`

```
    String json = null;

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("email",username));
    jsonObject.put("password",pass);
    json = jsonObject.toString();

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(strUrl);
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
    httpPost.setEntity(se);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: How can i post this JSONObject using the jParser

Answer (score 0):

```
public JSONArray executeService(String... params) throws Exception{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constant.AdsDetail.URL);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Constant.AdsDetail.PROJECT_ID, params[0]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Constant.AdsDetail.BROKER_ID,params[1]));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
        String output;
        StringBuilder responseJsonStr = new StringBuilder();

        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            responseJsonStr.append(output);
        }

        String queryString = Utils.getQueryString(nameValuePairs);
        System.out.println("Query String "+Constant.AdsDetail.URL +"&"+queryString);
        //System.out.println("Response Json String "+responseJsonStr );

        if(!StringUtils.startsWith(responseJsonStr.toString(), "[")) {
            responseJsonStr.insert(0,"[");
            responseJsonStr.append("]");
        }
        return new JSONArray(responseJsonStr.toString());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing which you want to use in your code its a call post a data to server in a `raw-data format`. Use my working below code:

```
public String POST(String url, JSONObject jsonObject) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        String json = "";
        json = jsonObject.toString();
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        if (inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return result;
}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

Now while you want to use or post data to server you need to use something like this:

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
 jsonObject.put("email",username));
 jsonObject.put("password",pass);
```

Now you need to call that method using

```
 String request = POST(yourURL , jsonObject);
```

***NOTE :*** While you'r using this `raw-data format` then you should set `Content-Type` to `application/json` at your `back-end` side otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Sorry am new to android. So how do I parse the response?

Comment: For parse you just check that if your first tag in response is `JSONObject` or not. If it is then it should be `JSONObject jb = new JSONObject(request)` and first tag is `JSONArray` then it should be `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray (request)` For more information go with this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/